# Knockout - sorting table with a fixed row

Tags: knockout.js

I was able to implement sorting as explained in this article
http://ryanrahlf.com/sorting-tables-by-column-header-with-knockout-js/

But I would like the last row in the observableArray to stay put. In our case, the last row is like a summary/total. Is it possible to sort an observableArray of object, but skip the last object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is: put sortable data in one array, the summary is another observable (maybe a computed), there's another computed that appends the summary to the sortable array. The final computed is what goes in the table, but the sorting is done on the first array.

Comment: Agreed, a total row should not be part of the array